# Better way to compare attributes of 2 objects of the same class with a lot of attributes

Tags: java, object, compare, comparison

If I have a class with a long list of attributes, what is the best way to compare 2 objects of it? I have tried using overriding `equals` and `hashcode` but the long list of attributes make it almost impossible to add a check to compare each attribute. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to compare these objects to sort them?

Comment: Use an IDE to generate those methods. And since Java 1.7 there are Objects.hash(...) and Objects.equals(...) that make it a bit easier.

Comment: @RalfRenz that's actually a great idea! Thanks!

Comment: You can make a helper method that accepts both objects, and an var-array of lambdas that would extract these attributes and compare them. It might be shorter and easier to reason about than IDE method gen.

Comment: @RalfRenz `Objects.equals(Object a, Object b)`  doesn't make the task of overriding `equals(Object o)` method any easier. The only thing it simplifies is the actual task of comparing two objects for equality. Custom classes still need to override these methods.